# Initializing queues

Tags: java, queue

Here is the declaration of an interface:

```
public interface Queue<E>{
        boolean isEmpty();
        void enqueue(E newElement);
        E dequeue();
}
```

And here is the initialization I want to perform:

```
public class Test{
        ......
        private Queue<dataType> queue1;
        private Queue<dataType> queue2;
        ......
        public Test_Constructor(A a, B b){
                ......
                queue1 = new ... *initialization
                queue2 = new ... *initialization
                ......
        }
```

How should I be initializing queue1 and queue2? That's a fixed template and I do not want to change any(No adding or deleting).

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to initialize the queue use Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();

Comment: @DhirendraGautam, no. In this case `Queue<E>` is not a JDK interface, it seems to be OP's own type.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov in that case interface needs its implementation and that implementation class object can be used as an initializer  just like in JDK LinkedList is implementation of Queue

Comment: The initialization of the two queues should be starting with "new."

Comment: @JuhyunPark what have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried new Queue<dataType>(); and got Queue is abstract; cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @JuhyunPark, that means you need to have some non-abstract subclass of `Queue<T>` which you can actually use with the `new` operator. Since the `Queue` seems to be your own class, you will have to write that yourself.